# Marshal Conflict between Rails/ActiveRecord versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, marshalling, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to run Rails 5 and Rails 6 simultaneously and have encountered a caching issue when the Rails 5 & 6 versions of the project share the same external cache. After the Rails
5 version of the project caches an ActiveRecord object, when the Rails 6 version reads from the cache and tries to read `cached_object.id`, it returns `nil`. Interestingly enough, `cached_object[:id]` returns the correct value.

Our caching implementation uses Marshal under the hood to serialize/deserialize, so I was able to reproduce this without the cache dependency, as follows:

Given a project running Rails 5:

```
usr = User.find_by_id(1)
puts Marshal.dump(usr)
```

Copy and paste the result of `Marshal.dump` to another console running Rails 6:

```
usr = Marshal.load(<COPY_PASTE_STRING>)
usr.id // returns nil
usr[:id] // returns 1
```

The opposite doesn't seem to be true (ie. `Marshal.dump` in Rails 6 and `Marshal.load` in Rails 5 doesn't reproduce this)

Is anybody familiar with the Rails internals that might know what's going on here?

Comment: thanks for this question and answer! I made a rails issue about it here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43582

Comment: Any luck fixing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this behavior isn't an issue with Marshal, but rather a [change](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b6828fc91531ae0cc0a0f216705dd19112596301#diff-4411c7993e3f8ccfd8e09f44a81f10dfac3ea7dbd44cabd60b369040a00be324) in ActiveRecord in Rails 6.